# Mongoose - Save Document to Another Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save a document to another model before delete it. But I cannot get it to work. Here is the representation of what I did.

**Schema**

I created a mongoose schema and created two models from it.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AccountSchema = new Schema({
  fullname: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
    // required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, "Please enter valid email!"],
    required: true
  },
  password_hash: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  salt: String,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  },
  updated: Date,
  updateCount: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

Create Models

```
const AccountModel = mongoose.model("AccountModel", AccountSchema);
const AccountModel_deleted = mongoose.model("AccountModel_deleted", AccountSchema);
```

I then created a function for a url parameter which return the user info based on its id. Example: (`/api/users/:the_id`)

```
const the_id = (req, res, next, id) => {
  AccountModel.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Cannot retrieve user with that id!"
      });
    }
    req.userinfo = user;
    next();
  });
};
```

I tried to save the data sent from the above method (`the_id`) to the database with the following method:

```
// MOVE BEFORE DELETE
const move_to_deleted = (req, res, next) => {
  const { _id, ...selected_user } = req.userinfo.toObject();
  const moved = new AccountModel_deleted(selected_user);
  moved.save((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err
      });
    }
    res.json({
      message: "Saved to database!"
    });
  });
  // End moving
  next();
};
```

By calling that method through this route:

```
router.route("/api/users/:the_id").post(move_to_deleted);
```

And execute it with the following method:

```
      fetch("/api/users/" + _id, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.loginInfo.token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

But it fails. It won't save and returning the following message:

```
Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/users/5c96fd6855040e2884efc097", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

### **What is wrong and how to fix it?**

I actually want to save the deleted account/ user data to different collection. But I still don't understand the difference between model and collection. So, It will be great if you can explain it as well.

Comment: did you mount `the_id`? Also in this middleware, `const the_id = (req, res, next, id)`, where does `id` come from?

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar That method is used as url parameter. I use express. So, I think express is doing it. Anyway, I managed to find the bug.